# Magento - SQL - Select all products by attribute and update it

Tags: sql, magento, attributes

I need to select all products with specific attribute (barcolor) and then update attribute with another value.

EXAMPLE.
I would like to select all SKU with `barcolor = LIGHT GREEN` and update them to `GREEN`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this from backend. you can go to `catalog > manage products > select all products >` at the right side you can see `update attributes` option , select that and click on submit and you will redirect to another page and than give the value in required field and save it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieve by programming also.

If you have attribute option ID than:

```
$sAttributeName = 'brands';
$mOptionValueId = 250;  // 250 is Id of Brand 1
$newOptionValueId = 255;    // 255 is Id of Brand 2
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        $sAttributeName,
        array(
            'eq' => $mOptionValueId
        )
    );

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
foreach($productsCollection as $product) {
    $productId = $product->getId();
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        array($productId),
        array('brands' => $newOptionValueId),
        $storeId
    );
}
```

If you do not have attribute option ID than you can use the option value directly as:

```
$sAttributeName = 'brands';
$mOptionValue = 'Brand 1';
$newOptionValue = 'Brand 2';
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        $sAttributeName,
        array(
            'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute($sAttributeName)
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId($mOptionValue)
        )
    );

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
foreach($productsCollection as $product) {
    $productId = $product->getId();
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        array($productId),
        array('brands' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute($sAttributeName)
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId($newOptionValue)),
        $storeId
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list of the entity_ids for all the products and you are using a custom attribute, you can run an SQL query for each and every product like so:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` SET value = 'NEW BLACK' WHERE entity_id = '12345' AND attribute_id = 'attribute_id_here';
```

You can also filter the fields by:

```
SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE value LIKE 'something';
```